# Socket.io firefox connection interruped on refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, socket.io

Error:

```
 The connection to 
 ws://localhost:8080/socket.io/1/websocket/fejoeV3q3S5wZTg9QZi7 
 was interrupted while the page was loading.
```

Source File: socket.io.js , Line: 2371

This error showing when i refresh page in firefox.

I use latest socket.io library (v0.9.6).

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like it's a Firefox issue ([Link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/socket_io/j7mxtHd4n3A))